# Unable to get my followers to follow me

Tags: diablo-iii-console

So, I've got two guys hanging out in New Tristram -- the Templar and the Scoundrel.

Based on what I've read, these are "followers" who can join my party. Thing is, I cannot for the life of me figure out how to get the to actually join the party. Dialogue options just make them talk.

So, how do I get them to join my party? If it matters, I am playing two-player local co-op (which is an absolute blast!).

Comment: @OrigamiRobot actually this isn't console specific (local co-op or not its still considered multiplayer) so you can probably just leave the diablo-3 tag and get rid of the PS3 reference.

Comment: Based on spartacus comment shouldn't the tag be diablo-3 and not diablo-3-console?

Comment: @Mike Per [meta](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7647/should-there-be-a-diablo-3-console-tag) they are different games with different tags.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I think the console tag is only used when its dealing with something that's console only.  Not for all questions about diablo-3 (whatever version).

Comment: @spartacus The precedent being used is Minecraft/Minecraft Xbox/Minecraft PE. For those we use the game being played regardless of whether they have the same behaviour on PC; we don't default to [minecraft].

Comment: @SevenSidedDie so if someone's asking about how to build a redstone repeater and they're playing the xbox version it'd be tagged minecraft-xbox only?

Comment: @spartacus Yep. I can see the problem you're getting at—where we have duplicate questions with just tag differences—but so far that hasn't actually been an issue. Meanwhile, inaccurate tagging *has* caused issues where answers are wrong because they're not talking about the same game, so the tagging is set up to avoid the real problem rather than the hypothetical one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can only add them when you play solo.  In solo, there will be an option to Hire the followers.